# How do I add a character at the end of every other line and delete its carriage return

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ 6.6.8
How do I add a character at the end of every odd line and also delete its carriage return, so that the next line connects with it.

For example I want this text:

```
present
هديه
I was first in ..
كنت الأول فى
like
مثل
front door
الباب الأمامى
promise - d
يوعد
back door
الباب الخلفى
```

to be like this:

```
present,هديه
I was first in ..,كنت الأول فى
like,مثل
front door,الباب الأمامى
promise - d,يوعد
back door,الباب الخلفى
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I added formatting so that the markdown editor would properly format your example text blocks. Double check that it still is formatted properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular expression pattern would work. In the Replace dialog, check "Regular Expression" and make sure ". matches newline" is unchecked. Replace All with Find:

```
(.*)\r\n(.*\r\n)
```

Replace With:

```
\1,\2
```

`\r\n` will match a Windows-style newline, and `.*` will match 0 or more of any character. \1 and \2 will replace with whatever was matched in the first and second groups of parentheses `()`. So it basically matches every two lines and replaces the first newline with a comma. It's not the greatest and requires your text to start on the first line (if it's mismatched add a newline before) but it should work for what you need.

Comment: The help you gave me will save me a lot of time. What is this place? its super fast. I'm so glad I joined. You were so kind, not just giving me the regex, but you even explained it to me. Thanks so much for your time and help.

Comment: @Muhammad This is SuperUser! It is one of many collaborative Question-and-Answer sites in the Stack Exchange network. If you enjoyed the help, we invite you to read over the [FAQ] and contribute answers to others when you have the knowledge. This whole place is built on nothing more than people asking good questions and giving good answers, and others editing those questions and answers to make them even better.

Comment: No problem, it's my personal mission to teach everyone how to use regular expressions!